# Query posts by taxonomy with current term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Is there a way to get posts by taxonomy with specifing the current term.

My post type is (listings),  and my taxonomy is (region)
I need to change adriatique term to the current term in my post

```
    $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'listings',
  'showposts' => -1,
      'tax_query'  => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'region',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => array('adriatique')
        ),
      ),
     'posts_per_page' => 5
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your query as a function if you have not already (so you can use it elsewhere) and pass the slug as a parameter to your function.

ie. `function get_listings_by_region($region)`

You can get the slug of the current term by using something like the following:

```
$queried_object->slug
```